# How to identify bad disk by WWN Windows Server 2008

Tags: hard-drive, command-line, windows-server-2008, software-raid, disk-management

I have two identical hard drives in Windows Server 2008 configured in diskmgmt.msc as a software mirror, or whatever MS's parlance is. One of the disks is bad. Good ol' Linux can show a drive's WWN in the output of `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id`, but I need to know if there's a way of identifying via software (diskmgmt, diskpart, disk properties, etc.) a disk's SN or WWN to match the info on the disks's label. `wmic diskdrive get` doesn't appear to offer any 1-to-1 information.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the `/all` switch for your WMIC command to get enough information to uniquely identify the disk drives:

```
wmic diskdrive get /all
```

You may also be able to get identifying information through Disk Management as follows:

1. In Disk Management, right-click the fixed disk and click **Properties**
   [image]
2. On the *Details* tab of the Properties window, inspect the various details exposed by the disk
   [image]

Some possible detail fields that will help identify a disk are:

- Friendly name
- Hardware IDs
- Bus reported device description
- Location information

Comment: The `/all` switch is implied if specific data isn't requested.
I looked through the details window for each drive (as stated, they're identical) and didn't find any info that explicitly differentiated the disks from one another. The SN listed in the wmic output doesn't match the SN format from a previous drive (I scanned the label). The "Location Information" isn't guaranteed to remain consistent across reboots.

Comment: Yeah, the usefulness of these details can be somewhat system specific, though the fact you're getting inconsistent serial number info is troubling. On every system I've ever run `wmic diskdrive` on, `/all` returns significantly more info. Not sure why you're getting a different result.